# Passing multiple url parameters in laravel 4

Tags: php, url, parameters, laravel

1
I need to pass 3 parameters (name,path,number) in update function
Here,below is the code for the same,Kindly, help me in the same.Help is appreciated

Routes:

```
Route::put('update_document_details/{name}/{path}/{number}',array('as'=>'update_document_details','uses'=>'AuthorsController@update_document_details'));
```

Controller:

```
public function update_document_details($name,$path,$number)
        {


            $document_details=Response::json(Author::update_document_details_by_id_Call($name,$path,$number));
            return $document_details;
        }
```

Model:

```
public static function update_document_details_by_id_Call($name,$path,$number)
    {
        return DB::select("call update_document_details_by_id('$name','$path','$number')");
    }
```

Comment: I don't why your code should not work. What is the problem then?

Comment: Yes, if you could let us know what is the problem you are having with the above code, it is easier to help you

Comment: ERROR:"MethosNotFoundException"
Now its solved.I have changed the code as follows:
Routes:
Route::put('update_document_details',array('as'=>'update_document_details','uses'=>'AuthorsController@update_document_details'));

Controller:
public function update_document_details()
  {
    $name=Input::get('name');
    $path=Input::get('path');
    $number=Input::get('number');
   
            $document_details=Response::json(Author::update_document_details_by_id_Call($name,$path,$number));
            return "Updated";
  }

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see a reason why the above code should not work, but you can try this as an alternative. This helps you not to pass your parameters on the URL if you wish to change.

**Route**

```
Route::put('/update_document_details','AuthorsController@update_document_details');
```

**Form**

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'update_document_details','method'=>'put'))}}
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="text" name="path"/>
<input type="text" name="numbe"/>
{{Form::close()}}
```

**Controller**

```
public function update_document_details()
{

   $name = Input::get('name');
   $path = Input::get('path');
   $number = Input::get('number');

   $response = Author::update_document_details_by_id_Call($name,$path,$number);
   return Response::json($response);
}
```

Couple of suggestions here, this might be helpful or may be not.

1. Why not use a [resource controller](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) instead of defining a seperate `put` route.
2. When asking a question, try to give as much information as possible, so that it is easy for us to help you in all regards.